# My static library isn't building right

Tags: ios, c, xcode, static-libraries

I tried to build a static library in Xcode. 
How I did it:

1. made a cocoa touch static library
2. deleted generated .m and .h
3. added my .h c header files
4. placed my added .h files in "copy headers" list in build phases
5. Build

But i noticed my generatedLibrary.a is still red and not really build. When i check the products folder in finder i see this:
[image]

The header files are not in an "include" folder as it should be, it's inside a use/local/include folder directory. And there is no generated .a file for it. Can I ask what went wrong?

Comment: Set active scheme to `iOS Device` (and then `iOS Simulator`). Worked? If not, are you building a universal library?

Comment: Hello sir, I tried those. I also noticed that if i don't do my step 2 and build it directly before doing anything else , it builds, with the correct include folder. Then i do my step 3 and build, it gets updated. But i also noticed that the headers inside my "Copy files" in build phases are inside an "include" folder while the headers in my "Copy headers" are inside the "usr/local/include" (as seen in image). Im not sure if its normal...

Comment: My goal is to build a static library for device and simulator and probably combine it using lipo -create when all goes well

Comment: You're doing it right. The best advice I can give is match your steps with this tutorial - [Creating Static Library in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial).